# How do I fix one signal app id invalid problem

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I have developed a Xamarin application and I am sending notifications via One Signal.
Everything works perfectly for Android. But I don't get notifications anymore in the IOS app.
The error I got is the One Signal App Id is invalid.
My certificates and everything seems to be working properly. How can I solve my problem? Please help me.

```
FATAL: OneSignal AppId format is invalid.
Example: 'b2f7f966-d8cc-11eg-bed1-df8f05be55ba'
```

Comment: Have you compared the App Id that you use with the Example of the error message? They should be appr. the same length and format.

Comment: I think they are in the same format, I saved it in the info.plist file like this. `<key>oneSignal_APP_ID</key>  <string>"myappıd"</string> `

Comment: But have you LOOKED at it? May we see it?

Comment: Of course I checked my app id information is absolutely correct

Comment: You can file a bug at One Signal, or double check if what you are actually sending to One Signal is what you intended to send. Low level debugging of your app?

Comment: I should also add that I can not see ios devices while I can see android devices logged in on one signal website